# Properties changes inside of MessagingCenter.Subscribe are not reflected outside of method

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am using an argument transferred using `MessagingCenter.Subscribe` to change the `Name` property, but outside of the `MessagingCenter.Subscribe` method, the change is not reflected, and the property stays at a null value.

I think that `MessagingCenter.Subscribe` is creating a separate instance of the property, but I have no idea how to solve this if that is the case.

**Sending the message**

```
            ClassPageViewModel classPageViewModel = new ClassPageViewModel();

            MessagingCenter.Send<MainPage, ClassListModel>(this, "ClassDetails", details);
```

**Recieving the message**

```
        public string Name { get; set; } 

        public ClassPageViewModel()
        {
            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MainPage, ClassListModel>(this, "ClassDetails", (sender, arg) =>
            {
                Name = arg.Name;
                Console.WriteLine(Name); //This outputs what I sent
            });

            Console.WriteLine(Name); //This outputs a null value

        }
```

Name has to be a property, because it is being bound to a label

and I cannot use a page constructor argument to transfer the string.

---------Edit---------

Creating second instance on second page (first instance was sending the message)

```
BindingContext = new ClassPageViewModel();
```

Comment: Your 2nd writeline is execute **before** the subscribe message is received.  Only code in the subscribe's delegate is executed after a message is received.

Comment: and, if you want your bound values to update automatically, you need to use INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: @Jason The console shows that that writeline triggers twice. It says null, the correct value, then null again.

Comment: you need to add something to your writeline so you can distinguish which one is being called multiple times

Comment: @Jason I did this, and can confirm that it is the second writeline being triggered twice. I think that it might be because I am triggering the viewmodel twice, once to send the message from one page, and once to bind info to another. My question is, why does Name switch back to null when I load the viewmodel again? And how can I solve this?

Comment: because you have two different instances of the VM.  That's how objects work - different instances are completely independent of each other

Comment: @Jason Ok, then how should I keep both pages using the same instance?

Comment: please show the relevant code where you're creating the two instances

Comment: @Jason Post has been updated

Comment: just create one instance in the first page and pass it to the 2nd page via the constructor.  I don't see any reason you need to use MessagingCenter to do what you're doing, either.

Comment: @Jason I cannot use the constructor because the next page is a TabbedPage, so MessagingCenter is the best alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public string Name { get; set; } 

public ClassPageViewModel()
{
    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MainPage, ClassListModel>(this, "ClassDetails", (sender, arg) =>
    {
        Name = arg.Name;
        //first line
        Console.WriteLine(Name); //This outputs what I sent
    });

    //second line
    Console.WriteLine(Name); //This outputs a null value

}
```

I think you can first understand when would those two lines be  printed.

The first line code will execute when you send `ClassDetails` message from `MessagingCenter`.

The second line code will execute when you create a new instance of `ClassPageViewModel`.

So back to your question:

> outside of the MessagingCenter.Subscribe method, the change is not
>   reflected, and the property stays at a null value.

At that time, you are just create a new instance of `ClassPageViewModel`, so you get null from the second line code.

> The second writeline triggers twice.

This should be caused by you created two instances of `ClassPageViewModel`.

> then how should I keep both pages using the same instance

There are many ways you can achieve that. Here is what I recommend you to do:

In class **App**, create a static property called `classPageVM` and custom the `classPageVM` 
there:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public static ClassPageViewModel classPageVM { get; set; }

    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //custom your classPageVM herer
        classPageVM = new ClassPageViewModel();

        MainPage = new MainPage();
    }
}
```

Then in the page you want to use this viewModel, you can use the same instance `App.classPageVM`:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.BindingContext = App.classPageVM;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course that it will output a `null` value. The default value of `string` is `null`. You have never initialised your `Name` property. It **will** be initialised once the subscriber (i.e. the page) receives the message. In your ctor you are simply subscribing to the topic, but you are not receiving anything (at least not in the initialisation itself). If you call the `WriteLine` method after you have sent the topic, you will see that the property will have updated value.

If you indeed *must* use the `MessagingCenter`, then the better approach is to initialise the `Name` property to have `string.Empty` so that some binding won't throw exception. And at some later point, when the `MessagingCenter` sends the message, the value will change itself.

NB: Keep in mind that you'll have to call `OnPropertyChanged` in order for the UI to know that the `Name` property needs redrawing.

Comment: The second writeline triggers twice. In the console the output is null, then the value I want, then null again. I do recieve the message, but the property changes back, or something.